# Is there a way i can link to standard merge leads screen by passing ids of leads to be merged

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a list of leads which i am allowing the users to select and merge from a VF page.
When we try to merge the leads from the find duplicates screen, the page is redirected to /lead/leadmergewizard.jsp.

How do i pass the ids of the leads to merge to the leadmergewizard screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect users to below URL with id as parameter,

```
/lead/leadconvert.jsp?id=00Qe0000004w123
```

It also takes retURL parameter specifying the Id of the record to which you would like the page to be redirected after conversion of lead.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the Lead Ids and you want to skip the Find Duplicates screen, and go straight to the Merge Leads screen, you can use a URL similar to this:

```
/lead/leadmergewizard.jsp?goNext=+Next+&id=00Q001&cid=00Q001&cid=00Q002
```

where you can add multiple `cid` parameters, where each one has a Lead Id as the value

Comment: Thanks.. Just a another question. can i redirect the page to another page after the merge. Currently it goes to lead list

Comment: Do you mean to redirect to the Lead that resulted from the merging, or to another unrelated page?

Comment: Normally you can use retURL/saveURL parameters, but these seem to be ignored for Lead merging. It usually redirects to the merged Lead